# Should the components be drawn in the Design System?

Tags: component, design-system

I wanted to investigate what an design system is, but there is a part I cannot understand.

In design systems, buttons, forms, that is, every component we see on the website or mobile application is placed as drawn in the design system, or only the rules are determined and the developer designs according to these rules?

The reason for my confusion is that the component designs on the [atlassian.design](https://atlassian.design) website do not seem to have much to do with the design on the Atlassian website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and welcome to the site! I think you are asking two things here, but I might be wrong:

1. By *every component [..] drawn in the design system*, do you
   mean you expect a visual for every component? There are parts of the
   design system which have no explicit visual representation (except
   by being followed in many examples).
2. By *component designs [..] have much to do with the [..]
   website*, are you asking whether (or why not) Atlassian is applying
   their own design system? For various reasons, that can be a complex
   task, and different companies achieve different success (at different points in time).

Comment: Yes, you understood my questions correctly, thank you for your answer, atlassian's design system confused me, so I wanted to ask.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard for what a design system is or what it should include, simply because it is a solution to the problem of how design concepts and ideas should be translated and implemented.

Depending on the maturity of the design and dev teams, as well as the type of products and services you want to provide, a design system can be a very high level way to communicate the intent and vision, or as detailed as a specification for every single component and behaviour.

In general, because you'll find that most design systems aim to solve common problems and have similar goals, the high level details don't seem to vary all that much. However, it is usually in the details that you will see the underlying details of how the implementation gives rise to the characteristics of different design systems.

Also, you might find that even using the same design system, it is entirely possible to come up with very different implementations.

Comment: I understand thank you for your answer.